# Is it possible to recover accidentally deleted HashiCorp's Vault secrets?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

According to [this tutorial](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/first-secret.html), it is possible to delete a secret, by running:

```
vault delete secret/hello
```

What will if someone in the organization accidentally removed a secret. Is it still possible to recover this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your secret backend is a separate service, which it should be, then with regular backups you should be able to stop vault, replace the backend with a backup and be good to go.

I've done this for a file backend but don't know what would happen for other backends so ymmv.

Comment: So for example do regular snapshots?

Comment: Basically yes. Depending on how often you add secrets your snapshots may become _very_ regular though.